# How can I get CGMiner to connect to mining_proxy.exe

Tags: cgminer, proxy

I'm trying to get my CGMiner to connect to my mining_proxy.exe which I have my network ASICminers running through.

I have tried these (below) in every combination I could think of, local ip, 127.0.0.1, local host, connecting directly to eclipse. you name it and it won't show the hashrate or what is happening in the mining operation.

```
- cgminer.exe -o  stratum+tcp://127.0.0.1:8332 -u worker -p 123456
- cgminer -o "http://127.0.0.1:8332|http://us.eclipsemc.com:3333" -u worker -p 123456
- cgminer -o http://127.0.0.1:8332 -u worker -p worker
```

I need CGminer showing my hashrate and have some control over the mining operation.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this..

cgminer.exe --userpass usertes.worker1:123 --url stratum+tcp://stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 --socks-proxy 127.0.0.1:1001

127.0.0.1:1001 is the proxy with port..
modify with ur own proxy